# How to password protect my webpage of 1 instance in ELB?

Tags: apache-http-server, amazon-web-services, password-protection, httpd, load-balancer

I have launched 2 instances with basic html page on AWS. And added those instances with one external ELB. I made the configurations like, only i can access those webpage by hitting the ELB and not by hitting the public or Elastic IP of each instances. Now, i have password protected only one instance's webpage. When i try to hit the ELB, i cannot access the password protected webpage and also in AWS console -> Load Balancer, that particular instance was in OutOfService. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the load balancer can not connect to the health check url. You can either disable the health check (leave the url empty), or serve an unprotected file for health check purpose, and change the url to point there.